# What Does $\cong$ (Congruence?) Mean in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I've tried to look it up, but I don't know what it means to say that $V^* \cong V$. Also, what do I say, "$V$ dual is congruent to $V$"?

Comment: In this context, that usually stands for *...is isomorphic to...*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In functional analysis there is a concept of the (topological) dual space $V^*$ of a normed vector space which is the set of continuous linear functionals $L:V\to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$, but in this case the isomorphism will end up being anti-linear). There is a natural way to equip $V^*$ with a linear structure so that it becomes a normed vector space too.

In very special circumstances, we may find that $V$ as a normed vector space is isometrically isomorphic to its dual $V^*$. In particular, if $V$ is a Hilbert space, then we get this for free. When this happens we write $V^* = V$ abusively, or if the author is more careful $V^* \cong V$.

It would be pronounced "$V$ star is isometrically isomorphic to $V$", or "$V$ is self-dual."

Comment: Do you know how one can show that they are _isometrically_ isomorphic when $V$ is finite-dimensional? $\hspace{.57 in}$

Comment: This follows from the (deep) theorem in functional analysis that any real Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to its own dual.  If you want an easy proof of the finite dimensional case, you can prove it yourself. Define the isomorphism to be $x \mapsto x^t$, i.e. change row vectors to column vectors. Can you show that this is an isometric isomorphism?

Comment: (It's a little bit of tedious work, but certainly doable, and by no means does it require as much theory as the Hilbert space case).

Comment: @nulluser : $\:$ I now how to do it for Hilbert spaces; I have no clue how to do it $\hspace{1.78 in}$ for _general_ finite-dimensional normed spaces. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Finite dimensional normed spaces (over $\mathbb{R}$) are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ which is a Hilbert space.

Comment: They are all _homeomorphically_ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its Hilbert space structure, but they are not all _isometrically_ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its Hilbert space structure. $\:$

Comment: Yes but I didn't claim it was isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, I claimed it was isometrically isomorphic to $V^*$. It is homeomorphically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ which may **after the fact** be equipped with its inner product structure to pull back an inner product structure to $V$.

Comment: Since the pullback inner product structure on $V$ won't induce $\:V$'s$\:$ norm, how does that help? $\hspace{.9 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Sincerest apologies I have been mistaken this whole time. Clearly $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $2$-norm is not isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $3$-norm so my argument must fail. I should have said finite dimensional inner product spaces (i.e. I should assume there is an inner product which induces the norm. In this case $V$ is a Hilbert space in its own right and the theorem applies directly).

Comment: I think you should replace "finite-dimensional" with "a finite-dimensional Hilbert space" in your answer. $\;\;\;\;$